# what is numpy random.RandomState

Tags: python, numpy, probability

```
import numpy as np 
rng=np.random.RandomState(123)
for i in np.arange(1,21):
    number=2**i
    heads_tails=rng.randint(0,2,size=number)
    ptails=np.mean(heads_tails)
    print("Number of tosses:",number,"---","Probability of Tails:%.2f"%(ptails*100),"%","---",
         "Probabilty of Heads:%.2f"%(100-ptails*100),"%")
```

***Hi,I wrote this code and I didn't understand the  random.RandomState's function in here,What is it using for or What is the function of that? If you can explain,I would be appreciated.***

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was your motivation for putting it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.random.RandomState()`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.13/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html) constructs a random number generator. `np.random.RandomState()` returns a new seeded `RandomState` instance but otherwise does not change anything. You have to use the returned `RandomState` instance to get consistent pseudorandom numbers.

For instance, if you use the functions in the `numpy.random` you will not get consistent pseudorandom numbers because they are pulling from a different `RandomState` instance than the one you just created. So to be consistent, you can create a specific `RandomState` and draw to pseudorandom numbers in a reproducible way.

Answer (score 2):

It is used to create a random number generator with a set seed (`123`).

It is useful because using `seed()` impacts the global numpy random generation, while RandomState will set the seed for the `rng` generator only (in your code).

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when you are using randomization in a part of the codebase, you want to get the same result independent of the iteration you are running the code. 
`np.random.RandomState()` set random state in all the `numpy` operations, if there are related with randomization. 
Else, you can set custom `random state` === `seed`, in every function that supports random_state parameter. 
Note: 
this is really useful in python model testing, machine learning model building, etc.